# How to make a z-index fit to page and not scalling

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, z-index

How to make a z-index fit to page and not scalling i need to put it up from an svg, but my svg is in fit to page.

here is my div code

```
<div   id="homeScreen" class="grey_box"  style="background-color:#CDCDCD;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 8px;
    width: 373px;
    height: 537px;
    visibility: visible;">
 <p class="hello" >E-Number<input id="tags" /></p>
<p class="hello2">Mat-Number<input id="tags1" /><p>
<p class="hello3">Tech. ID<input type="text"  name="fname"><p>
<p class="hello4">RIS<input type="text"  name="fname"><p>
<p class="hello5"> <button onclick="get_action_home()" style="width: 100px">Continue</button><p>
<p class="hello6">Βάση δεδομένων: Τοπικός</p> 
<p class="hello7">Σύνδεση: κομμένη</p> 
<p class="hello8">Κατάσταση βάσης δεδ.: Μη επίκαιρη</p> 

</div>
```

here is the javascript to put it dinamically

```
function adjust()
{

            var DMMScreen = document.getElementById("DMM");
            //new screens dinamic 
            var homeScreen = document.getElementById("homeScreen");



            homeScreen.style.height = DMMScreen.getBoundingClientRect().height;
            homeScreen.style.width = DMMScreen.getBoundingClientRect().width;
            homeScreen.style.top = DMMScreen.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            homeScreen.style.left = DMMScreen.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            //
```

and here is what i found from jquery but i don't know how to fix it

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#width").text($(this).width());
    $("#height").text($(this).height());
});
```

and here is the link for what it does 
[link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebsha1t091ewk40/good2.png) and
here is the bad when i change the window 
[link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/b7n4nn3gg2gb6fn/good.png)

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` doesnt fit to anything, it's a 'layering' tool, allowing you to place elements on top of each other, what i assume you mean is you have a `position:fixed` or `position:absolute` in conjunction with `z-index` .. if this is the case you can make the element fit to the page width by using `width:100%;`

For instance:

```
<style>
.full_width {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="full_width"> i will fit the width of the page</div>

    your other stuff here...
</body>
```

If this is not what you mean, then please provide more information..

**Edit**
The links you've provided, you don't need to use `position` or `z-index`,

this is going to be as simple as setting your `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto` and defining that container a `width`..

paste the HTML & CSS for that page into your question and we can give you more help

but as it stands, an example of getting that box in the middle of your page would be

```
<style>
.grey_box {
    width:500px;
    height:600px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
</style>
<div class="grey_box">
 <!-- your content here-->
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AbQsa/

Comment: the good one[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebsha1t091ewk40/good2.png) and here is the wrong one [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b7n4nn3gg2gb6fn/good.png?m) that is not fiting to the page!